# Dags triggered by DagTriggenRunOperator are stuck in queue

Tags: airflow

**example_trigger_controller_dag.py**

```
import pendulum

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id="example_trigger_controller_dag",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    schedule="@once",
    tags=["example"],
) as dag:
    trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="test_trigger_dagrun",
        trigger_dag_id="example_trigger_target_dag",  # Ensure this equals the dag_id of the DAG to trigger
        conf={"message": "Hello World"},
    )
```

**example_trigger_target_dag.py**

```
import pendulum

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


@task(task_id="run_this")
def run_this_func(dag_run=None):
    """
    Print the payload "message" passed to the DagRun conf attribute.
    :param dag_run: The DagRun object
    """
    print(f"Remotely received value of {dag_run.conf.get('message')} for key=message")


with DAG(
    dag_id="example_trigger_target_dag",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    schedule=None,
    tags=["example"],
) as dag:
    run_this = run_this_func()

    bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_task",
        bash_command='echo "Here is the message: $message"',
        env={"message": '{{ dag_run.conf.get("message") }}'},
    )
```

the task in controller dag successfully ended but the task in target dag stuck in queue. Any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are other DAGs on this instance working as expected?

Comment: Did you enable both the DAGS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your DAGs (with both of them unpaused) and they work fine in a completely new environment (Airflow 2.5.0, Astro CLI Runtime 7.1.0). So the issue is most likely not with your DAG code.

Tasks stuck in queue is often an issue with the scheduler, mostly with older Airflow versions. I suggest you:

- make sure both DAGs are unpaused when the first DAG runs.
- make sure all `start_date`s are in the past (though in this case usually the tasks don't even get queued)
- restart your scheduler/Airflow environment
- try running the DAGs while no other DAGs are running to check if the issue could be that the [parallelism](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#parallelism) limit is reached. (if you are using K8s executor you should also check [worker_pods_creation_batch_size](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#worker-pods-creation-batch-size) and with the Celery Executor [worker_concurrency](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#worker-concurrency) and [stalled_task_timeout](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#stalled-task-timeout))
- take a look at your scheduler logs (at `$AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler`)
- upgrade Airflow if you are running an older version.